# matplotlib plot datetime in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this `training.head()`

[image]

The DataFrame has been sorted by date. I'd like to make a scatterplot where the date of the campaign is on the x axis and the rate of success is on the y axis. I was able to get a line graph by using `training.plot(x='date',y='rate')`. However, when I changed that to `training.plot(kind='scatter',x='date',y='rate')` I get an error: KeyError: u'no item named date'

Why does my index column go away when I try to make a scatterplot? Also, I bet I need to do something with that date field so that it doesn't get treated like a simple string, don't I?

Extra credit, what would I do if I wanted each of the account numbers to plot with a different color?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the plotting code only considers numeric columns. Internally it selects just the numeric columns, so that's why you get the key error.

What's the dtype of `date`? If it's a `datetime64`, you can recast it as an `np.int64`:

```
df['date_int'] = df.date.astype(np.int64)
```

And then you're plot.

For the color part, make a dictionary of `{account number: color}`. For example:

```
color_d = {1: 'k', 2: 'b', 3: 'r'}
```

Then when you plot:

```
training.plot(kind='scatter',x='date',y='rate', color=df.account.map(color_d))
```

Comment: Right now date is a string. I'm not sure how to cast it to another data type.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.date)` may work. Is the `-0400` a timezone?

Comment: Yes `pd.to_datetime(df.date)` was able to convert the number to an integer which was then plottable. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've found it simpler to change the `style` of a line chart to not include the connecting lines:

`cb_df.plot(figsize=(16, 6), style='o')`

[image]

Comment: I believe this is not the same as a scatterplot -- this is just like using dashed lines.  The points are always uniformly spaced and do not necessarily correspond to the original data values.

Comment: @cboettig I guess it works only if the points on the x axis are sorted and the distance between consecutive points are the same.

Comment: if the x axis are sorted dates it works well, thanks!

Comment: One could also try `some_df.plot(x=my_dates,y=my_y,style='o') -- it seems to be working for me

Answer (score 2):

The plotting code only considers numeric columns, so the piece of code bellow will give you error:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

try `pd.to_numeric` as below and finnaly use `scatter plot`. It worked for me!

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Date)
```